convex combination in 2D plane.
Demonstrating Equality of Rates at Intersection Points on Parameterized Lines:
Consider a scenario in an M1M2 plane, where multiple lines are drawn, each parameterized by alpha and t. Here, alpha varies from 0 to 1 along the line, representing positions between the lower and upper ends. For any given line, t remains constant and is an integer which ranges from 1 to K. So, for a given value of t, we have one line in this M1M2 plane.
In this context, let's denote points as follows: A and B on one line, and C and D on another line. These points represent specific positions along their respective lines. The rate at any point along these lines is determined by the formula:
Rate = alpha * N * (K - 1) / K + (1 - alpha) * (K - t) / (t + 1)
where N and K are system parameters. Additionally, the memory parameters M1 and M2 are defined as follows:
M1 = (alpha * K2 / K) + ((1 - alpha) / (K choose t)) * ((K - K2) choose (t - K2)) * N
M2 = ((1 - alpha) / (K choose t)) * ( (K - 1) choose (t - 1) - (K - K2) choose (t - K2) ) * N
Suppose we assign beta to line AD and beta' to line BC. Then, the rate at the intersection point using line AD is given by:
Rate at Intersection Point (AD) = beta * Rate at A + (1 - beta) * Rate at D
Similarly, for line BC:
Rate at Intersection Point (BC) = beta' * Rate at B + (1 - beta') * Rate at C
Note that the line with A and B points on it will have the same value of t while finding the rate for these points, but alpha will be different for A and B. A similar concept applies to C and D.
We want to prove that, irrespective of the chosen line, the rate at the intersection point remains constant. How can we rigorously prove this equality of rates at intersection points using the provided formulas and the properties of convex combinations?
